# How to extract the estimates from a stanfit object

Tags: stan, rstan

Let `fit` be `stanfit` object. Then I can extract estimates of parameter `AAA` by the following manner:

**Expected A Posterior**

```
   EAP <- as.data.frame(summary(fit)[[1]])["AAA","mean"]
```

**95% Credible Interval**

```
   lower.CI <- as.data.frame(summary(fit)[[1]])["AAA","2.5%"]
   upper.CI <- as.data.frame(summary(fit)[[1]])["AAA","97.5%"]
```

But I am not sure, this is a canonical method ? If there is some more simpler code, then let me know.

---

Memorandum of Understanding

**EAP**

```
EAP <- get_posterior_mean(fit,par=c("AAA"))
```

Comment: There's an RStan vignette detailing poserior extraction:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/vignettes/stanfit-objects.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a mean, the `get_posterior_mean` function is perhaps a bit more canonical. For quantiles, I would just do something like `quantile(extract(fit, pars = "AAA")[[1]], probs = c(0.1, 0.9))`. However, the endpoints of 95% credible intervals are not estimated very precisely with the default settings for Stan.

Comment: Thank you, for rapid and kind reply , I  appliciate you very much for every reply !!

Comment: To estimates the precise endpoints of credible intervals, what I  have to change from default values ? Or any web page explain it ?

Comment: It is the `probs` argument to `quantile`.